# Find out if a method exists in a static class

Tags: php, static, object

I want to check is a function exists in a library that I am creating, which is static. I've seen function and method_exists, but haven't found a way that allows me to call them in a relative context. Here is a better example:

```
class myClass{
    function test1()
    {
        if(method_exists("myClass", "test1"))
        {
            echo "Hi";
        }
    }
    function test2()
    {
        if(method_exists($this, "test2"))
        {
            echo "Hi";
        }
    }
    function test3()
    {
        if(method_exists(self, "test3"))
        {
            echo "Hi";
        }
    }
}
// Echos Hi
myClass::test1();
// Trys to use 'self' as a string instead of a constant
myClass::test3();
// Echos Hi
$obj = new myClass;
$obj->test2();
```

I need to be able to make test 3 echo Hi if the function exists, without needing to take it out of static context. Given the keyword for accessing the class should be 'self', as $this is for assigned classes.

Comment: Why isn't the test1() method sufficient?

Comment: Because I want to put this into a class that will be extended by multiple classes. I could use a magic constant to achieve this, but there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`static::class` is available since PHP 5.5, and will return the "[Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)" class name:

```
class myClass {
    public static function test()
    {
        echo static::class.'::test()';
    }
}

class subClass extends myClass {}

subClass::test() // should print "subClass::test()"
```

[`get_called_class()`](http://ca.php.net/get_called_class) does the same, and was introduced in PHP 5.3

```
class myClass {
    public static function test()
    {
        echo get_called_class().'::test()';
    }
}

class subClass extends myClass {}

subClass::test() // should print "subClass::test()"
```

---

The [`get_class()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function, which as of php 5.0.0 does not require any parameters if called within a class will return the name of the class in which the function was declared (e.g., the parent class):

```
class myClass {
    public static function test()
    {
        echo get_class().'::test()';
    }
}

class subClass extends myClass {}

subClass::test() // prints "myClass::test()"
```

The [`__CLASS__` magic constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) does the same [[link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#44214)].

```
class myClass {
    public static function test()
    {
        echo __CLASS__.'::test()';
    }
}

class subClass extends myClass {}

subClass::test() // prints "myClass::test()"
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to check if a static method exists on the parent class, and this answer led me to discover that `get_parent_class()` works the same way when called without any params. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note `static::class` does the same as `get_called_class()`
and `self::class` does the same as `get_class()` but they are only available since PHP 5.5

Answer (score 14):

## Update:

Ahh, apologies. I was temporarily blind :) You'll want to use the magic constant __CLASS__

e.g.

```
if (method_exists(__CLASS__, "test3")) { echo "Hi"; }
```

Comment: this answer seems to be the same as the question example's test1() method using method_exists() with the class name passed as a string

Comment: The idea is that I don't need a class name, and I can therefore put the method in any class, and it should work, whether the class has been assigned or not.

Comment: You mean from the comments that I 'just' put on the main question?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I see you updated your comment in the OP with: "I could use a magic constant to achieve this, but there should be an easier way." I did not see this before I updated my answer.

What is not easy enough about the given method?

Comment: If extensibility is your goal, it should be noted that `__CLASS__`, `__TRAIT__`, `__FILE__`, etc explicitly returns the name of the class/trait/file where the constant is used, whereas if you want to account for child objects, you will want `get_class($this)` for instantiated objects, or `get_called_class()` for static classes/methods to track inheritance. Then you can drop one function in a trait or base class and use it everywhere, thereby preventing code duplication issues, and use `instanceof` [trait, parent class, or interface]  or `method_exists()` for validation without duplicate code.

Comment: Also in PHP 7+, the `static::PROPERTY` construct was added to simplify late static binding. Eg: `return self::PROPERTY` -> always returns from current class scope, `return static::PROPERTY` -> returns highest level declaration, honoring child class overrides of class constants, static functions, etc.

Answer (score -1):

for all situations… the best usage would be…

```
if method_exist(…) && is_callable(…)
```

For testing example:

```
class Foo {
  public function PublicMethod() {}
  private function PrivateMethod() {}
  public static function PublicStaticMethod() {}
  private static function PrivateStaticMethod() {}
}

$foo = new Foo();

$callbacks = array(
  array($foo, 'PublicMethod'),
  array($foo, 'PrivateMethod'),
  array($foo, 'PublicStaticMethod'),
  array($foo, 'PrivateStaticMethod'),
  array('Foo', 'PublicMethod'),
  array('Foo', 'PrivateMethod'),
  array('Foo', 'PublicStaticMethod'),
  array('Foo', 'PrivateStaticMethod'),
);

foreach ($callbacks as $callback) {
  var_dump($callback);
  var_dump(method_exists($callback[0], $callback[1])); // 0: object / class name, 1: method name
  var_dump(is_callable($callback));
  echo str_repeat('-', 40), "n";
}
```

Source [here](https://jmfeurprier.com/2010/01/03/method_exists-vs-is_callable/)