# Return string if method called inside of a class doesn't exist

Tags: php

Upon searching for hours, I've stumbled upon [method exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php), [function exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php), [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) and many other manuals, forum posts and blogs but they are either not clear enough for me or aren't what I'm looking for. In [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511549/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-function-exists-within-a-class) and [as well as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156593/find-out-if-a-method-exists-in-a-static-class), they are almost what I am looking for, only they check `method_exists` against a static method name.

Here's my issue:
I want a method inside of my class to check to see if `FunctionName` exists inside of the class `MyClassName` when called by `$foo = new MyClassName(); $foo->FunctionName();` and, if it does not exist, to echo "Test!". In other words, if the method being called doesn't exist in `MyClassName`, echo "Test!".

I know I can check it with objects like `$foo = new MyClassName();` and such, but I am looking for a **method/function** inside of my class that can do it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search took you exactly where you needed to go.

If you implement a __call method in the class definition (see the magic methods link you provided), it will be used when the method is inaccessible (doesn't exist or is private or protected, depending on whether you're calling the method from a child class or not, respectively).

Comment: So I would use it as the following? `public function __call() { echo "Test!"; }` ?

Comment: Yes, within the class definition. The method should accept parameters though - see the example in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) `__call()` and the function [method_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php).

Do as follows :

```
 public function __call($name, $arguments) {
      if(!method_exists($this, $name)) {
        echo "Method does not exist [called method '$name' with parameters". implode(', ', $arguments). "]\n";
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was aiming for more of a variable situation with just the __call magic method.

Comment: Use the button on the left to +1 ;) will be appreciated

Comment: The method_exists is redundant unless the method exists within the class itself (or a parent class's protected/public methods).